# WORDPRESS: Conditional Statements help reuqired

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Might be a simple one for some of you.

I am trying to pass a conditional statement in a Wordpress Header.php file to say that if you are on a page with the ID of 2, then have a class of 'home' my Banner Div, else leave blank.

```
<div id="banner" class="<?php if(is_page(2)){ 'home' } else { '' } ?>">
            <?php wp_cycle(); ?>  
</div>
```

This doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `echo` :)

```
<div id="banner" class="<?php if(is_page(2)){ echo 'home'; } else { echo ''; } ?>">
            <?php wp_cycle(); ?>  
</div>
```

Wordpress generally uses endif's, like so:

```
<div id="banner" class="<?php if(is_page(2)) : echo 'home'; else : echo ''; endif; ?>">
            <?php wp_cycle(); ?>  
</div>
```

Either way, if your else is empty, you don't need to even bother with it :) If your `if` isn't true, it won't echo anything, i.e.

```
<div id="banner" class="<?php if(is_page(2)){ echo 'home'; } ?>">
            <?php wp_cycle(); ?>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Silly me. I knew it would be something like that :-)

Comment: No problem :) I've been caught out a few times like that myself before too haha.